# Issue with asp.net website programming

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging

I have a site built in asp.net / c# . Basically user gives a station name and date time and it
brings in result from different car rental providers and show. I have developed similar sites before.

Unfortunately this time i am not sure why / how when i search a location abc on one computer at same time i search location bcd on another computer both will give me same result for which ever location that was processed first i am very confused to this matter and never have seen this before.

Any suggestion?

**CODE SUMMARY**

User comes to search page with **Location** and **Dates (from,to)** in **QueryString**

I take that and put them in **static variables.**

Than i run **6 ajax calls** as below:

```
function runthis()
{
        PageMethods.Site1(pageUrl, results_Car);

        PageMethods.Site2(pageUrl, results_Car);

        PageMethods.Site3(pageUrl, results_Car);

        PageMethods.Site4(pageUrl, results_Car);

        PageMethods.Site5(pageUrl, results_Car);

        PageMethods.Site6(pageUrl, results_Car);

}
```

Each will get the **Location** and `Dates` from static variable and will 
get the data and append to a `Div`.

Assuming reading my post should i use **Sessions** for **Location** and **Date** ?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @BenRobinson give me 2 mins uploading code..

Comment: looks like application variables are being used where session variables should be. but share your code then someone can help you better.

Comment: its 3 minutes now xD. please post some code otherwise we can't help u

Comment: Can you post your server side code, probably more pertinent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is static variables. 
This type of variable is application wide which means it remembers the first search result. 
The only way the value is cleared is by an application restart like restarting the application pool. 
You shouldn't make use of static variables. 
Try it out with normal variables and see if it works then.

Comment: If OP wants to persist the information for a given user, Session is a good option.

Comment: Depends on how the server side code is structured.  Your answer is not quite 100% correct.

Comment: @ Tim, Yes that is a good option. It's handy to make a sessionhelper class who does all the stuff for you like saving and reading from the session.

@ Paddy, yeah it could have more possibilities but this tackles the static variable though. I only can work with the code that was given.

Comment: @Everything is in Session now, still i get the same issue :|.

Comment: Hm... ok. maybe we need some more code to see what you have done. Did you remove the static variables?

Comment: yup issue solved , used Session Variables.One of them was still static :).